# Why would TSLint report errors in files but not list the files

Tags: typescript1.8, tslint, angular-cli

I'm running tslint via Angular-CLI and running into an issue where it is detecting failures but not showing me what the failures are.

This is the only output I get:

```
C:\extras\code\gitlab\project-name>ng lint

> Project-Name@0.4.0 lint C:\extras\code\gitlab\project-name
> tslint "src/**/*.ts"


Lint errors found in the listed files.
```

Why would this happen & how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is an error with Angular-CLI. If you run the command manually: `npm run lint` you can see the real error. I [submitted an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/867) on GitHub.

**Update**: This has been fixed, but until a new version is released, changing the bottom of your `tslint.json` file to this will resolve it.

```
"use-host-property-decorator": true,
"use-input-property-decorator": true,
"use-output-property-decorator": true,
"no-attribute-parameter-decorator": true,
"no-input-rename": true,
"no-output-rename": true
```

Related GitHub commit: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/848/files#diff-53fb140e7018814de9f2e231a3eb95a1R65